# Run all past jobs at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-schedule

I am using [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) to create an array based job-queue. However, I noticed that *node-schedule* only runs jobs in the future.

To prove this I created a minimum viable example:

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');

function randomDate(start, end) {
  return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}

let start = new Date()
let end = new Date()
start.setMinutes(start.setMinutes() - 35) // set job 35 Minutes in the past
end.setSeconds(end.setMinutes() - 10) // set job 10 Minutes in the past

/**
 * Create Scheduler
 */
let arr = []
const numb_jobs = 50
for (let i = 0; i < numb_jobs; i++) {
  d = randomDate(start, end)
  arr.push([i, d])

  schedule.scheduleJob(arr[i][1], function () {
    console.log('Job  -- #' + arr[i][0] + ' -- executed at: ' + arr[i][1]);
  });
}
```

Any suggestions how to run all past jobs at the beginning of the queue when the script runs?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I think this is a reasonable behavior. The time point (in the past) never reached, so the task never run.

Comment: Do you have specific use case?

Comment: @appleapple Thx for your reply! I am developing on electron and when someone starts the application all past jobs should run.

Comment: Then maybe execute those yourself? It'd be easy to say which task should be run.

Comment: or register a (long-live) service? (you still have to deal with power off time, though.)

Answer (score 1):

scheduleJob returns a job object.
You can cancel/reschedule and get data from the Job::invocations data.

https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/blob/master/lib/schedule.js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#jobreschedulespec